# Alternative definition of regular space.

Tags: general-topology

A space where every singleton set is closed is called regular if for a pair of a point and a closed set we shall get two disjoint open sets one contains the point and the other contains the closed set. This result of general topology is very familiar.

Let $X$ be a topological space such that any one point set is closed.. $X$ is regular iff given a point $x$ and a nbd of $x$ say $U$ there exists another nbd $V$ s.t. $\bar{V} \subset U$.

My question is that: Shall we consider every nbd $U$ of $X$ ? If the property holds for some special nbd of $x$, shall the space be regular ? Please give me an example to make it clear.

Thank you.

Comment: You need that _every_ neighbourhood contains a closed neighbourhood. Or in other words, the closed neighbourhoods form a neighbourhood basis for all $x \in X$.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

This being true for **some** neighborhood of $x$ is obviously not sufficient: You always have $x\in X\subseteq\bar X\subseteq X$. If you require the inclusions to be proper, it still does not imply regularity. Take for example $X=\Bbb R/(0,1]$, the quotient space. Here each point has a neighborhood $U$ such that $U\subset\bar U\subset X$, but the space is not regular, as the point $(0,1]$ and the closed set $\{0\}$ cannot be separated by neighborhoods.